# How to check the timestamp using script

Tags: bash, scripts

I need to check my timestamp after "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" and print it to this csv file.

What's wrong in this code?

```
#!bin/bash
echo %computername%, timestamp=$( date +%T ) >> "system_monitor.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`man date`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/date.1.html):

```
%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

So you want `date +%s`, *not* `date +%T`.

And if by `%computername%` you mean the hostname, use the `$HOSTNAME` variable or the `hostname` command. So, something like:

```
#!bin/bash
echo "$HOSTNAME, timestamp=$( date +%s )" >> "system_monitor.csv"
```